# Single URL to Multiple URL [sharepoint]

Tags: dns, intranet

I'm hosting a site on a sharepoint site on an Intranet.  I have multiple users who are in diffeent Federation Groups.  Is there a way that I can publish a single URL to the Intranet, which redirects users to different URLS depending on the group which they authenticate against.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Microsoft SharePoint is commercial software.  Have you tried asking your vendor for tech support on the product they sold you?

Comment: Very good point.  I will need to talk to the commercial team.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, you want to do this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

A way to redirect a user to a specific page, depending on his work group, could be, publish a URL which check user's authentication parameters and redirect him to the right URL using a php swich or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As Zanna commented, this is the way. But you will need to check user parameters before presenting the url. 
I suppose your are talking about an IIS server for the intranet, right?

Check this code: http://blog.furuknap.net/redirecting-users-based-on-group-membership

This guy did based on Group membership: HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole();

This is the path you need to walk through.

Also, seems that you can redirect Urls directly from IIS configuration server. This is named Url rewrite. You can check on the IIS admin.

This is more easy, but less hackable. 
So you can try this first:
Check in the rules, if there is a User based rule. So you can make the IIS server redirect the user to several diferente urls you configure.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/11/27/how-to-create-a-url-alias-using-iis-url-rewrite.aspx